# How to create a custom UnitTest report in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, customization

I'm having some difficulty understanding how I would go about changing a unittest report similar to:

```
======================================================================    
FAIL: test_equal (__main__.InequalityTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_notequal.py", line 7, in test_equal
    self.assertNotEqual(1, 3-2, "My Custom Message")
AssertionError: 1 == 1
```

to a report resembling:

```
Line 7: My Custom Message
```

How could I parse these reports?

Answer (score 2):

After further research, my problem can be solved by overriding the default TestResult class as seen here: [Turn some print off in python unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518043/turn-some-print-off-in-python-unittest)

or by using some third-party customization such as  [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), an [HTMLTestRunner.](http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html)

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to create a custom report based on the success/failure of individual test cases, you can create a custom TestRunner, which uses custom TestResult, and in TestResult class, override success and failure methods. This will provide the callback for processing as per requirement.

```
class CustomTestRunner(TextTestRunner): 
        def _makeResult(self): 
            return CustomTestResult(TestResult)
        def run(self, test) -> unittest.result.TestResult:
            # add implementation as per TextTestRunner run method here

class CustomTestResult:
       def addSuccess(self, test):
           super(CustomTestResult, self).addSuccess(test)
           # your logic to log success cases

       def addFailure(self, test):
           super(CustomTestResult, self).addFailure(test)
           # your logic to log failure cases
```

For reference, please check python unittest module.